# Stackoverflow disappearing answers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, answers

Hi,

I have stumbled across a disappearing answer. According to my user/recent page, user 0scar has posted an answer to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243507/rounded-corners-in-a-css-table-cell-layout/1244114#1244114). It's answer ID 1244114. But when I view the question, I cannot see his answer.

What's up? Bug?

Edit: Okay, so he deleted his answer probably. It would be nice if the user/recent page would indicate that the answer has been deleted. Currently it's confusing IMHO.

Comment: This just happened to me as well, and there really should be some kind of indicator showing that a question has been deleted. I figured it was some kind of cache problem till I came here.

Answer (score 6):

He deleted it.

> "deleted by 0scar 11 hours ago"

Users with 10k+ rep can see deleted answers. Nobody can hide from everybody ;)

Comment: Thanks. IMHO it should be indicated that it was deleted. See my edited question.

Comment: You may be viewing cache. Does it still say he participated?

Comment: I'm tempted to register the `everybody` nick. Is `nobody` still around using that nick?

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, when I view my "Recent Activity" page it still says that 0scar posted an answer to my question. No mention that the answer was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely he posted it and deleted it right afterwards, perhaps because there was a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1):

When a user deletes their own answer or the answer is flagged and deleted by a moderator, it will no longer show up.

The "recent activity" message will remain, because it is telling you that someone *posted* an answer, not necessarily that the answer is still there.

If you have over 10k reputation points, you will be able to see deleted questions and answer, and in that case, you would be able to read his answer, but you probably wouldn't gain anything, because there is usually a reason for its deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for the question on the other sites? A lot of questions are getting migrated to more appropriate sites.

Comment: You can migrate specific answers now? sweet.

Comment: @Ian: AFAIK, you can't that would break many things. Most likely he got confused on the question. *Have you tried looking for the **question** on the other sites? A lot of **questions** are getting migrated to more appropriate sites.*